# WinAPI's control's positioning not working?

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

When I tried to set my static control position at 0, 0 and size the same as window's size everything worked just fine. Control was placed the same as window, but when i tried to make control smaller and place it so that there's equal amount of space on every side of control it didn't work. At the top there was more space than at the bottom and on the left side ther was more space than on the right side. Could you please tell me how to do what i wanted to do? Code i was using:

```
1: ghStatic = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"STATIC", L"Foo", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 0, 0, 300, 300, hwnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

2: ghStatic = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"STATIC", L"Foo", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 75, 75, 150, 150, hwnd, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
```

Comment: The simple explanation, usually the correct one, is that you forgot about the borders.  To center a control, you have to use the *client area* size, not the window size.  "size the same as window's size" only *seemed* to work, it was actually too big.  You just didn't notice.

Comment: I thougth it worked, because I set window's colour to dark grey and resized it. I could see it's working. I'll try your solution. EDIT: You were right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are do you using the CreateWindowExW function to change the size of your hwnd? You cannot use this function to change the hwnd size, it is used to create controls, because it will be trying to recreate what was already created.
 Try use MoveWindow function to change the position and size of hwnd:

```
MoveWindow(YourHWND, x, y, w, h, TRUE);
MoveWindow(ghStatic, 75, 75, 150, 150, TRUE);
```

Comment: No I'm not doing that. I was just creating static control.